# On 17.04 , gnome programs refused to be erased and instead erased my program removal icon

Tags: unity, gnome, icons

I have Ubuntu 17.04.

I tried to erase the gnome user interface program and all related gnome programs using the orange "get/remove programs" icon and related window and they wouldn't erase. Prior to that I had succeeded in erasing other programs I never used.  I also tried to remove "Unity8"  because I thought that was more gnome stuff.

Instead, the  "get/remove programs" icon was erased.

When I log in the options for gnome are still there along with the Ubuntu default setting.

How do I bring back my orange "get/remove programs" icon and purge the evil gnome programs from my computer?

I have spent several hours using the Ubuntu 17.04 desktop guide to figure this out with no success.

Comment: by get/remove programs you mean software-center?

Comment: Explain what you do you mean by 1) _erasing program_ 2) _get/remove program icon_ and most importantly 3) _gnome programs_? What are they? Are you referring to the gnome shell?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We are not mind-readers here, and therefore can not automatically deduce what's going on and how to fix your problem. Please [edit] your question to include information like the specific names of the programs you want uninstalled, the errors you get while trying to uninstall them, and anything else that could help us help you faster. Please also see our [ask] help pages to get a crash-course into writing a great question that gets you the help you need as fast as possible. Also, if you haven't already, please check out our [tour].

Answer (score 6):

Though your terminology is very different than we use here, I'm assuming that by 1) *erasing program* you meant uninstalling or removing programming, by 2) *get/remove program icon* Gnome software which is used to install or remove applications and by 3) *gnome programs* and *gnome user interface program* you mean the gnome-shell and its session.

I also assume you can still log in to the Unity session. So, log in to the Unity session (marked as **Ubuntu (Default)** in login screen) and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> keycombo to bring up a terminal.

Now type this command into the terminal and hit Enter key. When asked, type your sudo password there.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-software
```

Once it's completed use this command to completely remove gnome-shell.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-shell gnome-session
```

Comment: "GNOME software" was such a terrible name for an application. In typical GNOME fashion...

Comment: @Seth I'd agree. They should have named this as "GNOME software center" or something like that.